# How can I use GDAL library as optional in my c++ program?

Tags: c++, gdal

I am creating a c++ program that can use GDAL (if present). I can check the presence of GDAL in the system but how I need to code my program to include/not include the GDAL libraries if my program was compiled using GDAL?

Many thanks,
Carlos.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What compiler? What build system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't used CMake, but if the library is available you can link with it and also pass a flag to the compiler defining a macro (e.g. `-DHAVE_GDAL`). Then in your source you use the preprocessor to check for `HAVE_GDAL` and only use GDAL functionality if it's defined.

Something like this in your source:

```
#ifdef HAVE_GDAL
// Use GDAL functionality
#else
// Use something else
#endif
```

Comment: Although CMake is a great tool, I think what the OP is after is to be able to use/not use GDAL _after_ it has been compiled with GDAL support.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you link your application to a shared object (DLL), your program will fail to start if the shared object is missing. I'm not sure if there's another way than to simply load the SO on startup, and if you get a handle to the library, use dlsym (or GetProcAddress on Windows) to get hold of the functions you need, and call them that way.

Comment: Yes, I know. But GDAL is optional. So my software can/cannot include the GDAL headers. So how can I code my application to include / or not the GDAL headers?

Comment: Oh, you can include the headers, but you cannot link your executable to the library.